# Требуется динамическое изменение цвета ячейки qtablewidget, штатным repaint слишком медленно

Tags: c++, qt5

Можно ли как-то ускорить перерисовку таблицы или есть кастомная таблица для qt, ну или хотя бы исходник для отрисовки таблицы, нужны только числа в таблице и возможность менять цвет ячейки. Желательно с поддержкой лайота кути.

Comment: штатный repaint - это перегрузка paintEvent(...) ?

Comment: не знаю даже если честно

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось проблема в хидерах, я попутно менял цвет ячеек хидеров, это старый баг кьюта, после удаления кода обработки хидеров репайнт стал занимать менее 1 мс, а что бы наверняка перешел на update(ax, ay, aw, ah), теперь 0мс)

Answer (score 0):

```
QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget;

QTableWidget* tableItem = table0->item(0, 0); // получить ячейку по row и column

tableItem->setBackground(Qt::yellow);
```

Comment: И? По факту данное действие исполняется по какому то внутреннему таймеру, и не приводит к немедленному окрашиванию ячейки, если менять цвет от 5 Гц без repaint никаких видимых изменений происходить не будет, а repaint это от 40 до 500 мс на перерисовку, на i5-7400. Для одного окна ещё терпимо но два и более уже беда.